# Changing the user executing the build script in Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: windows, bamboo

Here is my problem:

I have a python build script building a .air package and deploying it on a server. If I run this script from a cmd.exe window, there is no problem, the files are correctly created and deployed.

But I would like to use Bamboo to be able to build my app everytime I commit/push changes. I configured it but have a serious problem: the .air package is created but the deployment (with a fabric script) doesn't finish... I noticed that the process is launched by 'Administrator' in a cmd.exe and by SYSTEM trough Bamboo. I think that this is the problem (maybe SYSTEM cannot find the ssh host or whatever), so I wanted to know if someone knows how to change the user executing the script to 'Administrator'.

Comment: I found the answer! My Bamboo server is runned as a Windows service, so I edited its properties in order to log in as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the user that your bamboo server runs as. I recently posted an answer with details on how do just that in [Windows Mercurial global keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590200/windows-mercurial-global-keychain/8246540#8246540) . All the documentation for the windows stuff in the wrapper file can found at http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-nt.html .